# Data guard broker cascaded standby delay parameter is ignored

Tags: oracle-12c, dataguard, standby, cascade

I have 3 databases: db01 primary, db02 standby cascading, db03 standby cascaded.

I have configured broker parameters by the following way:

> ```
> DGMGRL> show configuration
> Configuration – DB_HQ_DR
> Protection Mode: MaxPerformance
> Members:
> db01 – Primary database
> db02 – Physical standby database
> db03- Physical standby database
> Fast-Start Failover: DISABLED
> Configuration Status:
> SUCCESS
>
> DGMGRL> edit database ‘db01′ set property RedoRoutes='(LOCAL:db02)(db02:db03)’;
> Property “redoroutes” updated
>
> DGMGRL> edit database ‘db02′ set property RedoRoutes='(LOCAL:db01)(db01:db03)’;
> Property “redoroutes” updated
> ```

--Configured delaymins parameter:

> ```
> DGMGRL> edit database ‘db03′ set property DelayMins=’21600’;
> ```

When selecting log_archive_dest_2 parameter on db02 I see that there is delay parameter 21600 as it should be.

> ```
> SQL> show parameter log_archive_dest_2
>
> log_archive_dest_2   |  service="db03",  delay=21600 optional compression=disable  max_failure=0 max_connections=1 reopen=300
> ```
>
> db_unique_name="db03" net_timeout=30, valid 
>   _for=(standby_logfile,all_roles)
>
> ```
> DGMGRL> show configuration
> Configuration – DB_HQ_DR
> Protection Mode: MaxPerformance
> Members:
> db01 – Primary database
> db02 – Physical standby database
> db03- Physical standby database (receiving archived redo)
> Fast-Start Failover: DISABLED
> Configuration Status:
> SUCCESS
> ```

Problem is that apply process is not delayed. It applied as soon as there is generated archive log.
What happens? Why delay parameter is ignored?

Comment: Read through the usage notes on here & see if any apply to you https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28294/log_arch_dest_param.htm#i77472

Comment: So bad, it means I cannot have sync cascading and delayed cascaded standby 

@JSapkota I have seen this before and did not want to believe. Please post your comment as answer and I will accept it. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want delay apply on Cascaded Standby you need to set the `DELAY` of `LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_n` on Primary.

> The `DELAY` value that a cascaded standby uses is the value that was set for the `LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_n` parameter on the primary that shipped the redo to the cascading standby.

Reference:[DELAY](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SBYDB/log_arch_dest_param.htm#SBYDB01105)